# How to use if-else logic in Java 8 stream forEach with another list

Tags: java

I have a situation when the list will be returned

```
List<String> list2 = list
.stream()
.map(str -> someCondition(str) ? doSomething(str) : doSomethingElse(str))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`doSomething(str)` - This action returns `List<String>`

`doSomethingElse(str)` -This action returns only `String`

Can I collect them(`List<String>` and `String`) as a common List using `.collect`? If you have other opinions please let me know. Thanks

Comment: `List<Object> list2 = ...` should work

Comment: If you do declare `list2` as `List<Object>` then you'll end up with list2 containing some elements that are strings and some that are lists of strings. Is that what you're aiming for or do you want to flatten those lists so that list2 contains only strings?

Answer (score 3):

Just as if you were writing a method, you need your statement to return a consistent type. At the moment:

```
 str -> someCondition(str) ? doSomething(str) : doSomethingElse(str)
```

... returns either `List<String>` or `String`, so the nearest common superclass is `Object`. You probably don't want this. I would make it always return `List<String>`:

```
Function<String,String> myFunc = str -> someCondition(str) 
     ? doSomething(str) 
     : Collections.singletonList(doSomethingElse(str));
```

(I've stored your function in a variable so we don't have to use it inline in later examples. You can still inline it if you prefer.)

Now how you use it depends on what you want to end up with. If you want a `List<List<String>>`:

```
List<List<String>> list2 = list
    .stream()
    .map(myFunc)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But since you appear to want a `List<String>`:

```
List<String> list2 = list
    .stream()
    .flatMap(myFunc.andThen(List.stream))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

... or if you prefer ...

```
List<String> list2 = list
    .stream()
    .map(myFunc)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Much better answer than mine - +1